# VBA: Send mail via Outlook in Excel for Mac 2011

Tags: vba, macos, email, outlook

On a Mac, Office 2011 (latest patches) I want to send a mail via Outlook

```
Set mailer = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
```

which gives the error

> ActiveX component can't create object

which seems believable since there is no ActiveX on the Mac.

I tried to find alternative solutions, but

- they are quite dated (2011)
- the macro has to work on both Mac and Windows

What is currently the best VBA way to send a mail via Outlook in Office Mac 2011?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

cf/ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh859489(v=office.14).aspx

As you note, Mac does not have `ActiveX` components.

For your VBA, use the above link to handle the Mac case, and use an `if` statement (see pseudo-code below):

```
If Application.OperatingSystem = "MAC" Or Application.OperatingSystem = "Macintosh" OR ...
    DoMacSendMail
Else
    DoWindowsSendMail
End If
```

Comment: this was perfect. I love the username ;)