# Run-time error 2147467259 (80004005) In Excel

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I am getting error 2147467259 (80004005) when I run the following code in Excel

```
Private Sub Button1Query_Click()

Dim OutLookApp As Object
Dim OutLookMailItem As Object
Dim iCounter As Integer
Dim Response

Set OutLookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.application")
Set OutLookMailItem = OutLookApp.CreateItem(0)

With OutLookMailItem

    .to = Sheet1.Range("AP5")
    .cc = Sheet1.Range("AQ5")
    .Subject = Sheet1.Range("D2") & " " & Sheet1.Range("B5") & " " & Sheet1.Range("E5") & " " & Sheet1.Range("F5") & " " & Sheet1.Range("G5") & " " & Sheet1.Range("C5") & " " & Sheet1.Range("D5")
    .Body = Sheet1.Range("H5").End(xlDown) & " " & Sheet1.Range("G4").End(xlDown).Offset(0, -1)
    .Send


End With

Set OutLookMailItem = Nothing
Set OutLookApp = Nothing

Response = MsgBox("Is Your query complete? If Yes click on YES button to Send Mail", vbYesNo, "CONFIRMATION BEFORE SENDING MAIL")

Sheet1.Range("H4").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 3).Value = "a"

End Sub
```

Can you please explain why and how to fix it?

Comment: Is there not some error text with that error code?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  I've had a go at tidying up your question, but it could still be better.  Could you please have a look at the advice in http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and add a little more context - e.g. Where you hit the error and what you're hoping this code will do for you?

Answer (score 0):

Excel Mac VBA is unable to create an ActiveX Outlook object instance like this.  This code will only work in Excel for Windows.

You can look at MSDN for examples of how to send emails from Excel for Mac https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh859489(v=office.14).aspx

If you want this code to be common and run in either environment, you will need to test which one you are running and handle it accordingly.  See this Stackoverflow question for an example. [VBA: Send mail via Outlook in Excel for Mac 2011](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20030084/vba-send-mail-via-outlook-in-excel-for-mac-2011)